# Inverse of the subtraction of Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus

I would like to compute $$(\mathbf{P}-\frac{1}{\sigma^2}\mathbf{I})^{-1},$$ which I already have $\mathbf{P}^{-1}$ and $\mathbf{I}$ is the identity matrix. It is not clear to me how to compute it for instance from *Sherman-Morrison* formula. I can write $$(\mathbf{P}-\frac{1}{\sigma^2}\mathbf{I})^{-1}=\mathbf{P}^{-1}+\mathbf{X}.$$ and then I have $$(\mathbf{P}-\frac{1}{\sigma^2}\mathbf{I})(\mathbf{P}^{-1}+\mathbf{X})=\mathbf{I}.$$ Doing a bit of math, I will get $$\mathbf{X}=\frac{\mathbf{P}^{-1}}{\sigma^2\mathbf{P}-\mathbf{I}}.$$ But computing the denominator is expensive. Any suggestion how to calculate it?

Comment: What makes the Sherman-Morrison formula for $(A-uv^t)^{-1}$ work is that the 2nd matrix is $uv^t$ which is just an $n\times n$ matrix with each row a constant multiple of $v^T$. An identity matrix is about is far away from this property as possible. I suspect, but don't know for sure that you won't have much luck since this is quickly related to a matrix geometric series $I+A+A^2+\cdots=(I-A)^{-1}$ when the spectral radius of $A$ is strictly less than $1$. I would just use gauss-jordan elimination on $[X|I]$ where $X$ is your matrix.

Comment: @N8tron Isn't there any exact solution without doing any expansion?

Comment: Well that depends are these $n \times n$ matrices or operators?

Comment: @N8tron they are matrices.

Comment: Then just use row-reduction (called Gauss-Jordan Elimination). The standard technique in an elementary linear algebra class is to take the matrix $\left[P-\frac{1}{\sigma^2}I | I\right]$ and row reduce it to $[I | X]$ then the matrix $X$ is the desired inverse.

Comment: There is also [Woodbury formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity) but I am not sure if it is useful in your case.

Comment: The woodbury formula looks like it applies but then you'd have to compute $\left(\sigma^2I-\mathbf{P}^{-1}\right)^{-1}$  or something like that

Comment: Since $$I=\sum_{k=1}^n e_ke_k^T$$ you can use Sherman-Morrison in a sequence of n calculations to get the result. But it's likely to be less efficient than calculating the inverse directly.